# Horizontally aligning images in separate divs in a ul

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I am trying to align images horizontally but they are all lying on top of each other.

I am pretty new to this so struggling to figure this out!

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div class="social">
     <ul>
       <div class="facebook">
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       </div>
       <div class="twitter">
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       </div>
       <div class="youtube">
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       </div>
       <div class="vimeo">
          <li><a href="#"></a></li> 
       </div> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
.social {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.social ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.social ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.facebook a:link {
    background-image: url(../img/facebook.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.facebook a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
.twitter a:link {
    background-image: url(../img/twitter.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.twitter a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
.youtube a:link {
    background-image: url(../img/youtube.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.youtube a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
.vimeo a:link {
    background-image: url(../img/vimeo.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.vimeo a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Here is the code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hdnrwrmj/

Comment: Remove the absolute position

Comment: What are the divs for? Inside a ul, it's weird and seems to serve no purpose as removing them and placing the class on the li seems to give the same result

Comment: @user1835565 it's so i can target each behaviour of the images i'm using

Comment: `<div>` elements are not valid direct descendant of `<ul>`. Only `<li>` is. What you're seeing is the browser's attempt to correct invalid markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to remove the `div`s and add the class names to the `li`s and also remove the absolute position. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/47k5o0ay/)

**EDIT:** Also use `inline-block` display for `li`s

HTML

```
<div class="social">
     <ul>
          <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li class="twitter"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li class="youtube"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li class="vimeo"><a href="#"></a></li> 

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.social ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.social ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;

}
.facebook a:link {
    background-image: url(http://www.cruisedeals.com/images_shared/top-deal-star-35px.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.facebook a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
.twitter a:link {
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ca/thumb/a/a0/Logo_upc.png/35px-Logo_upc.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.twitter a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}

.youtube a:link {
    background-image: url(http://data.cyclowiki.org/images/thumb/d/dc/ClericiMariani.png/35px-ClericiMariani.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.youtube a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
.vimeo a:link {
    background-image: url(http://mkhx.joyme.com/images/mkhx/thumb/8/88/%E5%9C%B0%E7%8B%B1.png/35px-%E5%9C%B0%E7%8B%B1.png);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-position: left;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.vimeo a:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated `HTML & CSS` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/27at51gg/)

I have removed div in ul. its not actually as per standards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the updated fiddle:-
And put your <div> inside the <li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnsqcL2t/